# How to get remote access to Linux interface

Tags: remote-access

Hi I am trying to access my school Linux system remotely. I have downloaded Putty and now get a terminal where I can type command and run the scripts (remotely) that already exists in my school Linux system.

But I cannot see the Ubuntu interface. So, I cannot see the output files from the scripts. Also cannot create new scripts.

Is there anyway that I can remotely access and see Ubunta interface (same as when I remotely access to Window system)? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xRDP](http://www.xrdp.org/) An open source remote desktop protocol(rdp) server.

Based on the work of FreeRDP and rdesktop, xrdp uses the remote desktop protocol to present a GUI to the user.

This worked for me with following Steps !

**Step 1 – Install xRDP**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

**Step 2 – Install XFCE4**

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Optional, recommended by Neal, install XFCE4 terminal and 2 icons sets:

```
# Install XFCE4 terminal (way better than xterm)
sudo apt-get install xfce4-terminal

# Install icon sets
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-full tango-icon-theme
```

**Step 3 – Configure xRDP**

In this step we modify 2 files to make sure xRDP uses xfce4.
First we need to create or edit our *.xsession*  file in our home directory.
We can either use nano or simply redirect an echo statement (easier):

```
 echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession

 nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

The content should look like this (pay attention to the last line):

```
#!/bin/sh

 if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
. /etc/default/locale
export LANG LANGUAGE
fi

startxfce4
```

**Step 4 – Restart xRDP**

```
sudo service xrdp restart
```

Now you can access your Machine Remotely !

From Windows Machine give try with Win+r and type *mstsc*:

[image]

Type user name and password :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to see the gui like via remote desktop protocol, innit?

Multiple solutions would be avaible for this, but no one knows what your School's admins have installed nor allowed you to run...

Learn how to deal with the command line.

Scripts don't need more.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could install something like VNC on their computer, and use a VNC client on your computer at home. 
You could also use TeamViewer if you want, but VNC is better and more secure. 
If you setup a VNC server make sure to set a password on the server. 
You may need to portfoward with VNC, and probably teamviewer.

Comment: VNC on its own is **far** from secure, even with a password - if you go that route you should for sure keep the VNC port closed and tunnel the VNC traffic over an SSH connection.

Answer (score 0):

X2go works brilliantly for me. I can even start long-running processes remotely, then close everything on my local machine, start up x2go again the next day to check on them, and things are still humming along.